# Stretch a polarplot() slice

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, polar-coordinates

I'm plotting some polar coordinates in Matlab. See example below:

[image: slice]

I'm only plotting a slice but can't figure out how to stretch/ expand this slice, as there is more space in the figure window than used. Speaking in pictures I'd like to 'open it like a fan'.
Minimal working example:

```
th = linspace(-pi/2,pi/2,100);
polarplot(th,1.1+zeros(size(th)),'g');
ax = gca;
thetalim([-5 5])
rlim([1.05 1.12])
```

I've tried using `ax.Position = [0 0 1 1];` similar to how it works in Cartesian plots but this does not seem to work here.

Any commands or tips I'm missing so far?

Comment: I don't quite get what you need. What is the purpose of `thetalim([-5 5])`? Does `thetalim([-35 35])` achieve what you want? Otherwise, if you really stretch the theta values the actual angle in the figure will not correspond to the theta value. Is that what you intend?

Comment: Your second assumption is correct. I'd like to only stretch the explicit range of e.g. [-5 5]. I'm aware that this will not visually represent 'true' angles anymore but the axis ticks will still show the numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of a workaround solution: increase the theta values passed to `polarplot` to get larger angles in the graph, and then relabel the theta axis:

```
stretch = 3; % stretch factor
th = linspace(-pi/2,pi/2,100);
polarplot(th*stretch,1.1+zeros(size(th)),'g'); % apply strech to theta
ax = gca;
thetalim([-5 5]*stretch) % take stretch into account when setting theta axis limit
rlim([1.05 1.12])
ax = gca;
ax.ThetaTickLabel = strsplit(num2str((ax.ThetaTick/stretch))); % correct theta labels
```

In the last line I am keeping the default theta ticks and relabelling them. You may prefer to specify other values manually, such as

```
ax.ThetaTick = stretch*(-5:5); % specify theta ticks, including stretch
ax.ThetaTickLabel = strsplit(num2str((ax.ThetaTick/stretch))); % correct theta labels
```

[image]